# Unable to Complete MongoDB Install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, gnupg, mongodb

I'm following [MongoDB's official guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for installing on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm unable to get past step three. I've tried importing the public key and created the list file. When I attempt to execute `sudo apt update` I receive the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease                                   
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease                 
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                            
Hit:5 https://download.ni.com/ni-linux-desktop/LabVIEW/2023/Q1/f0/community/deb/ni-labview-2023/jammy jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease                 
Hit:7 https://download.ni.com/ni-linux-desktop/2023/Q1/deb/ni/jammy jammy InRelease
Hit:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease                  
Hit:9 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Get:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release [3,094 B]
Hit:11 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A26B1AE64C3C388
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

After executing the following command provided by the guide to import the public key, I noticed that the file */usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg* had not been created.

```bash
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.pub | sudo gpg -vv -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg
```

Output:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=525
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1645629114, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 6A26B1AE64C3C388
# off=528 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=55
:user ID packet: "MongoDB 6.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>"
# off=585 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=574
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 6A26B1AE64C3C388
    version 4, created 1645629114, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 00 e1
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2022-02-23)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 9 len 4 (key expires after 5y0d0h0m)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 5 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 3 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 5 (pref-hash-algos: 8 2 9 10 11)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 3 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 6A26B1AE64C3C388)
    data: [4096 bits]
pub   rsa4096 2022-02-23 [SC] [expires: 2027-02-22]
      39BD841E4BE5FB195A65400E6A26B1AE64C3C388
uid           MongoDB 6.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
sig        6A26B1AE64C3C388 2022-02-23   [selfsig]
```

How can I resolve this error? Am I importing the public key improperly?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)  *Your sources match a Pop OS system, not a Ubuntu OS*

Answer (score 5):

I was able to import the key by executing the following:

```
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-6.0.asc | \
sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg
```

I then updated the list file appropriately:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/keyrings/mongodb-server-6.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
```